# Keyboard shortcuts are not working when unity plugin in ccsm is disabled?

Tags: unity, compiz, keyboard, unity-2d, shortcuts

**I am using ubuntu 11.10 with unity 2d , I dont like the unity launcher and use Docky .**

So , i have created a new seeion and using some tweaking and playing around i have been successful to get rid of the unity launcher and make a perfect interface that i like , but there are two problems ..

1. Keyboard shortcuts not working

   I had to disable the ubuntu unity plugin in ccsm to get rid of the unity    laucher..when it is enabled , i can use the keyboard shortcuts such as alt+tab etc ..

   But when i disable it , I am unable to use some shortcuts , I can still use some shortcuts like alt+F4 ect.
2. When I maximise a window , it used to show two window (close , maximise , minimize )buttons and title bars So , i set the window decoration in ccsm to !maxvert from any , and it is working fine for most of the time until i try to snsp the window to a side then the title bar just disappears , leaving space between the panel and the window , I cant close this window until i use the alt+mouse to drag it out , because no buttons would be displayed ..

Comment: I use compiz instead of metacity to handle my desktop

Comment: feel free to edit your question if you have any extra information you want to add.

Comment: I downvoted your question, because it is almost impossible to answer without knowing what modifications and customisations you've made to Unity. If you don't like Unity's interface, I highly recommend installing an alternative like GNOME, KDE, Mate, XFCE or LXE instead of customising it so drastically.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-main compiz-plugins-extra
```

Then restart ccsm. This will give you a host of new compiz plugins. For alt-tab window switching see Application Switcher, Ring Switcher, Shift Switcher or Static Application Switcher. They all provide the same basic functionality in slightly different forms. Look around and you'll find plugins for other keyboard shortcuts you may be used to.

I believe unity bundles that functionality so Ubuntu doesn't install these plugins by default.

I'm not sure about #2. I'll see if I can dig anything up ... That will be a bit trickier though since it sounds like Ubuntu's merging of the title bar with the top is happening but Unity isn't around to handle it.